# Set query parameters on the current route

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a problem with Angular2 router. I am displaying multiple lists on which user is able to select items. I would like to pass id's of these selected items as query parameters to the current/activated route so i.e.:

1) when user is on the main page with both lists the url is: `localhost/#/main`

2) when user selects item from the first list the item should remain selected and url should change to `localhost/#/main;firstItem=1`, but both lists should be still visible - no route redirection,

3) for the second list it should be similar so after selection url should change to `localhost/#/main;firstItem=8,secondItem=9`

I've already implemented passing query parameters from the child component/route - item management (on save or cancel to select item on the list) with:

```
this.router.navigate(['/main', { firstItem: item.id }]);
```

And it works ok, the resulted url is i.e.: `localhost/#/main;firstItem=1`.

However I cannot set query parameter on the activated route which is in this case desired behavior. Simple, similar to above solution throws an error that outlet has not been activated.

Any ideas or suggestions?